# Datagridview Filtering Error / Vb.net Sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, listbox, multipleselection

My problem is that i can not filter datagridview by multiselected items in listbox.

I can filter datagridview by multiple textboxes, comboboxes and one item selected listboxes. However, i can not filter with listbox multiple selections. Any ideas how can i solve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: sql tag? Explain how?

Comment: @Raging Bull 
MYBindingSource.Filter = _
        String.Format("mycolumn Like '%" & ListBox1.Text & "%' AND mycolumn2 Like '%" & ComboBox1.Text & "%'")

My codes like this. I use sql server -mdf.

Comment: Put the code in the question, and not in the comment. I have a hunch about what is wrong but I can't be sure without the code. Also add some of the surrounding code, not just only that line.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just go ahead and post my hunch based on your comment:

ListBox.Text will supply you the first selected item.ToString(). This means that when you select two objects it still only presents you with the first. What you have to do is loop through the different ListBoxItems and add them one by one separately. So what you looking for is something like this:

```
Dim Result As String = String.Format("mycolumn2 Like '%{0}%' AND (", ComboBox1.Text)
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1
    Result &= String.Format(" mycolumn Like '%{0}%'", ListBox1.SelectedItems(i).ToString)
    If i <> ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1 Then
        Result &= " OR "
    Else
        Result &= ")"
    End If
Next
```

I am not sure that the paranthesis will work, but I half expect it to. This will create a filter that requires mycolumn2 to match the textbox (as before), and then requires mycolumn to match any of the selected ListBox1.Items.